# Indexed Family of Sets Union and Intersection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I have a problem with understanding indexed family of sets. The problem is:

For each number $n$, let $\beta n=\mathbb N-\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and let $β=\{βn:n∈ℕ\}$.

I need to find the union and intersection.

For the union, I think it is $\{2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$

However, I am not sure how to check for the intersection. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If $k$ is in the intersection of all $\beta n$ then $k\in \Bbb N$ and $k > n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Is there such a $k$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, $k∈N$ but how is $k>n$"

Comment: I asked, can there be any $k\in \Bbb N$ with $k > n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Yes that is possibile

Comment: Is it? Which $k$ would that be? Notice that if $k\in\Bbb N$ and $k > n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then $k > k$. ... So, is *anything* in the intersection of the $\beta n$?

Comment: No $x\in N$ can belong to EVERY $\beta n$ because $x \not \in \beta x.$

Answer (score 1):

A number is a member of the union if and only if it is a member of **at least** one of the sets.

A number is a member of the intersection if and only if it is a member of **every** one of the sets.

The sets are

\begin{align}
\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,\ldots\} \\
\{3,4,5,6,7,8,\ldots\} \\
\{4,5,6,7,8,\ldots\} \\
\{5,6,7,8,\ldots\} \\
\{6,7,8,\ldots \} \\
\vdots\quad \\
\vdots\quad
\end{align}